# создание asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

когда в terminal пишу команду dotnet new mvc создается mvc ,а потом когда запускаю dotnet run и перехожу на localhost:5000 включается вот такая страница , почему?раньше когда создавал mvc не было такого backgound a [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Откройте инспектор, посмотрите код, откройте студию, посмотрите код вашего проекта, посмотрите где что подменяется. Вам наверное гораздо проще посмотреть на месте, чем нам гадать, что это могло быть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> когда в terminal пишу команду dotnet new mvc ... включается вот такая страница , почему?

Потому что [данная команда](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new) использует [template engine](https://github.com/dotnet/templating) для создания проекта. Так как Вы создаете Web проект, ожидаемо наличие различных ассетов. От версии к версии они меняются - не могу предоставить доказательства, но на моей памяти это случалось неоднократно.

---

Вы можете найти кастомный шаблон, установить его через NuGet и затем использовать при создании проекта (или же указать идентификатор необходимого шаблона с помощью ключа `-i`).

Посмотреть список доступных шаблонов для **mvc** можно следующей командой:

```
dotnet new mvc -l
```

Список всех доступных шаблонов:

```
dotnet new -u
```

---

Так же Вы можете создать свой шаблон - см. [линк](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/tutorials/cli-templates-create-item-template#).